# How do you lead these premises to this conclusion "d → c" with rules of inference?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

These are the premises:

1. (a∧¬b) ∨ (c∧¬b)
2. ¬b→((d∧a)→e)
3. e→(b∧¬f)

And they should lead this conclusion: d→c

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

premise 1:

$(a\land\neg b)\lor   (c\land \neg b)\implies \neg b\land (a\lor c)$

if premise 1 is true  then $\neg b$ is true and either $a$ or $c$ is true.

premise 2:

$\neg b\implies ((d\land a)\implies e)$

$\neg b$ is true by premise 1
so :

$d\land a\implies e$ is true by premise 2.
so $e$ is true whenever $a$ and $d$ is true.

premise 3:

$e\implies (b\land \neg f)$

so whenever $e$ is true $b$ and $\neg f$ is true.

but
from premise 1, $b$ is false, so $b\land \neg f$ is false.
this implies $e$ is false.

implying $ d\land  a$ is false in premise 2

so, if $a$ is false by premise 1, $c$ is true.
Now $d$ can be either true or false.

Remember that in implication only the consequent has to be true.

So the case $a$ false leads to $d\implies c$.

Case $a$ is true, then $d$ is false in premise 2.

And in premise 1, $c$ can be either true or false.
But again $d\implies c$ is still true.

Since the implication is false only if $d$ is true and $c$ is false.

Comment: Thank you! but can you show me which rules from the rules of inference you used and how you used them?

Comment: I suggest you lookup Patrick Suppe's introduction to logic, section 2.2